# uisegmentControl 1px space left between segments

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]there is 1px space left between uisegmentControl segments.how can i remove this space! 
in ios6 it looks fine but in iOS7 looks weird

```
NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"By Date",@"By Name", nil];

NSLog(@"ios6");

if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seg_se_r1.png"] xOrigin:150 yOrigin:30]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal],[[self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seg_un_l1.png"] xOrigin:150 yOrigin:30]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal],nil]];
} else {
    segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seg_se_r1.png"] xOrigin:150 yOrigin:30],[self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seg_un_l1.png"] xOrigin:150 yOrigin:30],nil]];

}

segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex=0;
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segmentedControl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

[segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10 , 300, 30)];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(pickOneSegment:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[self.viewSegmentControl addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: Can you attach an image?

Comment: @vokilam he cant attach image because of his reputation

Comment: yes i need some upvotes to add image :(

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove segment dividers

```
[self.segmentedControl setDividerImage:[UIImage new]
                   forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
                     rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected 
                            barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Note that you need to remove divider for different combinations of left/right segment states.

Comment: thanku so much for the answer but unfortunately i cant upvote you right now :(